# LinqToSharepoint insert to list with multiple content types

Tags: .net, linq, sharepoint

I have a problem inserting new records to a SharePoint list which can contain items of more than one content type when using Linq2SharePoint.

My list, and its content types, are created by a feature and in the event receiver content type bindings are created for a number of content types. These are in fact a tree of types inheriting from each other which all derive from one custom content type which itself derives from the built-in Item content type.

My data context is generated by SPMetal and then from this a repository layer is created using custom T4 templates. I am not using Linq2SharePoint to access named lists but rather to create  repositories for content types. Indeed as the list in question can be created in any SPWeb by activating the feature it doesn't exist at compile time so is unknown to the data context.

On MSDN it is explained that to handle lists of more than one content type SPMetal generates the data context to use the nearest base content type for a list of this nature. See the 'Generating entities for content types' section here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798478.aspx

Based on this I access the list using the base content type. For example assuming the following content type hierarchy:

```
Item
  Foo : Item
    BlueFoo : Foo
    RedFoo : Foo
      BrightRedFoo : RedFoo
      DarkRedFoo : RedFoo
    GreenFoo : Foo
```

Then my list can contain items of any of the XXXFoo content types and to access it  the data context uses an `EntityList<Foo>`.

This works perfectly for reading items from the list albeit they are all of type Foo rather than their derived types (though this is no real problem as using some jiggery involve a ICustomMapping extension to Item to access the hidden content type field the generated repository layer can access the underlying SPListItem and down cast to the derived type too if required).

The issue arises when I try to write an item to the list. First I tried to create a specific EntityList for this purpose e.g. `EntityList<RedFoo>` but this caused an exception. So then I added the Foo type to the Lists content types too and tried to add an item using an `EntityList<Foo>` but this causes the same exception.

The exception is the same in both instances and the error message is "Columns associated with mappings have been deleted/renamed". A Google search for this finds just the one happy fellow who encountered this message, (omourad.blogspot.com/2010/06/columns-associated-with-mappings-have.html), but his issue was incorrectly naming his list. This is not my problem.

After a couple of hours trawling the WWW I am finding very little discussion on SPLists with multiple content type and practically nothing relating to Linq and this issue. There is this on CodePlex http://sporm.codeplex.com/ but it has 0 downloads and has been quiet since 2009...

I have tried accessing directly from the data context rather than using the repository layer to make sure the problem isn't in my code. I've regenerated the data context from a web with the feature activated so that I can be certain its not out of sync.

Am I missing something? Is this fixed by a cumulative update I have somehow missed? Surely I am not the only person who has tried to do this? I feel almost as lonely as when you have a problem and the only online reference you can find is a StackOverflow tumbleweed question. There must be someone out there who can stop this being a tumbleweed question of its own?

Comment: Hi Rob,
Could you go over how you solved the Foo problem? I'm confused about how you are supposed to model this in L2SP and it seems like you solved it "using some jiggery". 

As far as your type problem goes I've been successful in adding a subtype to the base type list. What exception does it throw when you try?

Comment: Here is a link to a question I posted about it

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9386437/linq-to-sharepoint-multiple-content-types-for-a-single-list

Comment: Hi Jason. I posted an explanation of and a code sample for using ICustomMapping to provide the necessary "jiggery" to be able to resolve to the derived type from a L2SP base entity on your other question. Hope it helps. With regards to my problems with insertion via L2SP I didn't so much fix these as was happy to seem them disappear when we made some changes to our ContentTypes. After much digging around there is definitely a little inconsistency in the implementation of the Inherits attribute in 2010 though it wouldn't be fair to entirely rule out my own ineptitudes contribution ;)

Answer (score 0):

[Insert graphic of tumbleweed here]

I don't have a clear answer to this issue as seemingly it is not really a problem, or at least the manifestation I had was only a symptom. Or maybe I just don't have a clear answer as there are no clear answers in SharePoint world where it is seemingly perfectly acceptable to say "Don't do X" or "You must do Y" without really being able to explain or justify it. In this spirit I would say the following inappropriately unsupported generalisations:

Don't use the 'Inherits' or 'Overwrite' attributes on ContentTypes.

They sound good. The docs look good. The functionality would be fabulous for things like getting rid of that irksome 'Title' field but in truth they just don't seem to work. I don't know why, and I'm guessing neither do the SharePoint team as the best they can give me is 'An error occurred. Please try again' or some such. What I do know is without these two attributes and the highly desirable effects they confer everything works much better.